# Google Geocoding v2 API stopped working suddenly

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

The Geocoding v2 API stopped unexpectedly.

e.g.
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=27703&output=json&key=AIzaSyBVr3n3IVZzakGvtIWeRaJEXsC63JHZ0w8

I'm not able to get lat,long from the API. The output from server is:

```
{
  "Status": {
    "code": 610,
    "request": "geocode"
  }
}
```

I searched for `status: 610` but could not find any relevant info.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The service has been stopped.

It is the 8th of March.

See [the top of this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/v2/) for information on the death of v2

See [The Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) for v3

...

Edit.

Actually, there is a page about [upgrading to v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodingupgrade) that may be of use.

...

Edit.

As just pointed out, the Geocoding API V2 deprecation timeline was just extended by another 6 months, but be careful of your usage.

From @FrVaBe's link:
"Today we’re also reducing the limit on Geocoding API V2 from 15,000 requests per day to 2,500 requests per day, which is equivalent to the daily limit on the Geocoding API V3."

Comment: +1 for pointing out that unexpected behaviour could be expected since 2010 ;-)

Comment: (facepalm) thanks for pointing out. will migrate to V3. Thanks

Comment: Geocoding API V2 deprecation timeline was just [extended by another 6 month](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.de/2013/03/an-update-on-geocoding-api-v2.html).

Comment: Haha too many people got stuck in the same boat Shash did. Still, at least Shash knows to migrate now :)

Comment: Looks like the bug is not related to the deprecation timeline. As @FrVaBe points out, it looks like the issue is with the key being used.

Comment: is this usage limit is per api key or per ip?

Comment: Afaik v3 does not require a key. So the limit would be by ip. Care should be taken if encoding server side or client side however.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are using Geocoding API V2. You can find the list of status codes [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/v2/index#StatusCodes). The status you get is

```
610     G_GEO_BAD_KEY  
The given key is either invalid or does not match the domain for which it was given.
```

So check to use the right API version (obvious V3 - V2 has been stopped as @Rafe mentions)

I never used this API but request should have [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests) form

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/output?parameters
```