# Google Map Api request stopped working

Tags: php, google-maps, csv

I have a site that uses the below url to return the longitude/latitude for a location.

http://maps.google.co.uk/maps/geo?q=ph128uj&output=csv

It uses the part 2 & 3 of the information (long/lat) to compare locations. Suddenly this morning everything stopped working. Everything has been returning 0 for longitude & 0 for latitude.

Has anyone also had this problem, is there a new url or something we need to use. I have tried googling and looked at the "similar questions" here on stack overflow but everything keeps telling me to use this (or the json version) but every attempt returns a 610status code and no long/latitude.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15288244/2110460 is the same issue. You are still using the v2 option (as well as no key as @Micha said). Although the v2 has been extended, it would be best to do the upgrade now instead of waiting or you will face the same problem in 6 months.

Answer (score 4):

You're using the Geocoding API V2 that is deprecated since March 8, 2010. As you can see at the top of the [Google Maps Developers Documentation Page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/v2/), it was supposed to be working until March 8, 2013 (last friday).

> Note: The Google Maps Geocoding API Version 2 has been officially
>   deprecated as of March 8, 2010. The V2 API will continue to work until
>   Mar 8, 2013. We encourage you to migrate your code to the new
>   Geocoding API. Please refer to the upgrade guide for information on
>   how to migrate to the v3 API.

You have to migrate to New API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/guide

Answer (score 0):

610 is a GoogleMapsError: Error 610: G_GEO_BAD_KEY, meaning something is wrong with your API key.
It is required to send an api key with the request.

Best is to use the official Google Geocoding API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=nl