# Google API key just stopped working

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

Today I started getting the 'invalid api key' error from Google, after years of the code working just fine. Started today. Example:

This does NOT work:

http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=dallas&output=xml&v=2&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBtU9NELBF88O3yYqSjhkbTL2SkPe1xum0

This DOES:

http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=dallas&output=xml&v=2&sensor=false&key=ABQIAAAAzAkrOIsv60fbtV-5UlnnJxRUrcFJRfPs1DYZSl5DdA7w5qtvARRv6HblVCIt_AgTSnG3PdPypHTBEQ

Also, clicking the link doesn't work, but pasting it into directly a window does... why?

Both are valid API keys, yet I think the latter is an older version of one. But I had been previously using the former URL just fine until today.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Geocoding v2 API stopped working suddenly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288244/google-geocoding-v2-api-stopped-working-suddenly)

Comment: Have you tried looking at code.google.com/apis/console/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Sensor=false is a required input and no longer optional with the V3 API. You should migrate to V3 as V2 will ultimately stop worrking september 2013.
The URL and parameters change as well as the format of the json and xml response

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests