# Geocode function returns 610 code and codestatus badkey

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I am using googlemaps.subgurim.net google map in my project. Geocode function working fine an till 8 march 2013. After I am facing problem in geocode function it returns code 610 and code status badkey. Here I am converting latitude and longitude to human readable address.now it was not working.. how to solve this...

```
GeoCode objAddress = new GeoCode();
objAddress = GMap1.getGeoCodeRequest(new GLatLng(12.55,77.55));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if (objAddress.valid)
{
    sb.Append(objAddress.Placemark.address.ToString());
    string address = sb.ToString();
    lblPlace.Text = address;
}
```

Comment: This means your API key is bad, coming from the wrong IP, or maybe you're not providing one at all.

Comment: Follow the twitter saying Subgurim Maps @SubgurimMaps It looks like there are some technical problems with the v2 Geocoding API we are using, We are investigating the issue. Source: https://twitter.com/SubgurimMaps/status/311750648616075264

Answer (score 0):

The 610 code maps to this error:

```
The given key is either invalid or does not match the domain for which it was given.
```

Sounds like there may be an issue with your API key. Take a look at this question, as it may explain more: [Google Geocoding v2 API stopped working suddenly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288244/google-geocoding-v2-api-stopped-working-suddenly)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, with code that worked fine a few days ago.

Google said they are discontinuing their geocoding API v2 as of March 8, however, they say they have postponed EOL to September 8, 2013 (see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/v2/ )

API keys used to be optional, but right now it does not work either with no key, or with a previously valid key.

It looks like the only solution is to port to API v3.

Answer (score 0):

i added new version of Gmaps.dll version 4.1.0.5 file from:http://en.googlemaps.subgurim.net/descargar.aspx .
i am added this file to bin folder in my project.
After This i am activated my google API key to  Google API V3. for reference please refer this link:
:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

after this my project is working fine.