# Request Latitude Longitude - G_GEO_BAD_KEY

Tags: php, google-maps, geocoding

I have a script in `PHP` to get Latitude and Longitude of an address.
I never used an `API KEY`, but the code always worked. Weeks ago, it stopped to work So, I get an `API Key`. However, isn't working.

Follow a part of the script:

```
function loadURL($url){
    if (function_exists('curl_init')) {
       $cURL = curl_init($url);
       curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
       $result = curl_exec($cURL);
       curl_close($cURL);
    } else {
       $result = file_get_contents($url);
    }    
    if (!$result) 
       return false;        
    return $result;        
}
```

I did a test with another example:
**1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA**

The same example that Google uses.

Here is the url:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/geo?q=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&output=csv&sensor=true_or_false&key=your_api_key

I put my `API key`, set `true` or `false` to sensor, but the result is:

```
Status: 610 (**G_GEO_BAD_KEY**)
```

Why?

Comment: You may find http://stackoverflow.com/a/15289007/2110460 to be of  help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the  v2 version of the geocoder.  The v2 geocoder only works with v2 keys which are no longer available [(reference: this post in the Google Maps API v2 group)](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_frm/thread/6076465c15645dac#)

If you have a v2 key use that.  If not, get a v3 key and transition to the [v3 Geocoding web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/).