# Google maps Restful Webservice - Wrong Location

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, netbeans-7

I was testing the Netbeans tutorial about Restful WEbservices [Getting Started With Restful Webservices](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html)

Everything seems to be working , but the problem is that whatever address i give, the maps always shows the same location.(Near Africa on Equator. Think its the default location). I got an api key from Google as described in the tutorial.

Tried to read the response from firebug. There are  no errors, but the response is not easy to understand.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've found a solution or not yet, but I ran into the same problem and after looking around a bit, came to the conclusion that the problem lies in the returned value from the geocoding query (look for 'codeStr' in GoogleMapService.java).

The tutorial uses v2 of the Google Geocoding API and this problem is related to Google Maps' depreciation of v2 on the 8th of March 2013.  I'll bet you are receiving a 610 code from the Geocoding API instead of the expected response, so the marker is plotted at 0 lat, 0 long.

You can find more information about the change in the GoogleMaps API [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288244/google-geocoding-v2-api-stopped-working-suddenly), and at the site for the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/v2/).  Hopefully, the creator of the tutorial will update it to get it into a working state again as it is otherwise a good source of information.

Then again, it could be the Netbeans implementation of the RESTful api that has been affected by the depreciation of v2.