# 3 different urls 3 different ways for geocoding.What is the correct way of doing it?

Tags: geocode, google-geocoding-api

All I want is to get the geocode for the given address.Im doing it in Java.
Earlier I used the url like

"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=" +URLEncoder.encode(addrToFind, ENCODING) + "&output=csv&key=" + MyKEY

it returned me comma separated result like (status_code,lat,lng,precision)
Then for some alien reasons this url started giving me status code 610(invalid api key)
I regenerated the Browser key from Google but in vain.

Then i got another way to geocode the new url just trucated the 'geo' word in previous url

"http://maps.google.com/maps?q="+URLEncoder.encode(postcode, "UTF-8");

I extracted latitude and longitude from end result of this url but i noticed that this url gives me the whole html page as its response while all i want is just lat lng and precision.

Then I finally found a whole new url
"//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address="+address_to_geocode;
This gives me the Json response from which i extracted required information.This url doesnt ask for api key too.
What is the correct way of doing Geocod from above 3 or is there any other optimal way ?

Answer (score 0):

For the first URL, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288244/google-geocoding-v2-api-stopped-working-suddenly/15289007#15289007), that is the deprecated v2 Geocoding API, its lifetime has been extended, but it is not recommended for new development.

The second URL is a [Google Map](http://maps.google.com), and is not documented for use as a Geocoder.

The current [v3 Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) is the one you should be using.

Comment: Thanks.So the third url which im using is the V3. Just out of curiosity what about the second url i specified in my question is it one of the ways or is just a bad practice ?