# Google map shows blue screen

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to implement a google map marker in my web site. But it shows only a blue screen and a marker . I am not able to see any map there . Please see my code below. I have replaced the apikey with mykey.

```
    <?

define("MAPS_HOST", "maps.google.com");

define("KEY", "mykey"); // Place your API Key here...

// Get our address (from a database query or POST

$address = "india";

// Build our URL from the above...

$base_url = "http://" . MAPS_HOST . "/maps/geo?q=" . $address . "&output=csv" . "&key=" . KEY;



// Initalise CURL

$c = curl_init();

// Get the URL and save the Data

curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $base_url);

curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// Save location data

$csvPosition = trim(curl_exec($c));

// Close the connection

curl_close($c);





// Split pieces of data by the comma that separates them

list($httpcode,$elev, $lat, $long) = preg_split("/[,]+/", $csvPosition);

?>



<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title>Geocoding Example - WinSysAdminBlog.com</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

<style type="text/css">

  #map_canvas { height: 512px; width: 512px; }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript"

    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function initialize() {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat; ?>, <?php echo $long; ?>);

    var addressMarker = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat; ?>, <?php echo $long; ?>);

    var myOptions = {

      zoom: 16,

      center: latlng,

      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),

        myOptions);



    marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map:map, position: addressMarker });

  }



</script>

</head>

<body onload="initialize()">

<h2>Geocoding Example</h2>

  <div id="map_canvas"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance.
Sincerely,
Sunil

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, but I would say something about your Maps request is malformed, or else Google cannot find the address you're searching for (which seems unlikely). Try pasting the fully-formed URL into your browser and manually inspecting the CSV data you're getting back.

In the event Google cannot provide a geocode for your address, you'll get back 0, 0 as the latitude/longitude, which is the ocean beneath Togo off the coast of Africa. Might explain the blue square you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are attempting to use the [deprecated v2 geocoder](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.au/2013/03/an-update-on-geocoding-api-v2.html).  Use the [v3 Geocoding Service instead](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

[Issues have been reported with the v2 version of the API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288244/google-geocoding-v2-api-stopped-working-suddenly)